# Javascript creates infinite loop with scrollby and onscroll

Tags: javascript

How do i set up scrollBy on onScroll event without ending in infinite loop?
this just creates infinite loop of scrolling and onscroll event.
how do i break it, and make onscroll scroll only by 10 pixels?(without creating any additional setTimeout and trigger variables)

```
window.onscroll = function(){
                scrollBy(0,10);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the browser, when it detects scroll by your mouse, scrolls again because of the function `scrollBy()`, and so he calls the function `window.onscroll` again and again...
You just did an infinite loop!

To fix that you can do a boolean switch like this one:

```js
let scrollSwitch = true;

window.onscroll = function() {
    if(scrollSwitch) {
        scrollBy(0, 5);
        scrollSwitch = false;
    }
    else {
        scrollSwitch = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>
Primi igitur omnium statuuntur Epigonus et Eusebius ob nominum gentilitatem oppressi. praediximus enim Montium sub ipso vivendi termino his vocabulis appellatos fabricarum culpasse tribunos ut adminicula futurae molitioni pollicitos.

Quo cognito Constantius ultra mortalem modum exarsit ac nequo casu idem Gallus de futuris incertus agitare quaedam conducentia saluti suae per itinera conaretur, remoti sunt omnes de industria milites agentes in civitatibus perviis.

Ergo ego senator inimicus, si ita vultis, homini, amicus esse, sicut semper fui, rei publicae debeo. Quid? si ipsas inimicitias, depono rei publicae causa, quis me tandem iure reprehendet, praesertim cum ego omnium meorum consiliorum atque factorum exempla semper ex summorum hominum consiliis atque factis mihi censuerim petenda.

Montius nos tumore inusitato quodam et novo ut rebellis et maiestati recalcitrantes Augustae per haec quae strepit incusat iratus nimirum quod contumacem praefectum, quid rerum ordo postulat ignorare dissimulantem formidine tenus iusserim custodiri.

Nihil est enim virtute amabilius, nihil quod magis adliciat ad diligendum, quippe cum propter virtutem et probitatem etiam eos, quos numquam vidimus, quodam modo diligamus. Quis est qui C. Fabrici, M'. Curi non cum caritate aliqua benevola memoriam usurpet, quos numquam viderit? quis autem est, qui Tarquinium Superbum, qui Sp. Cassium, Sp. Maelium non oderit? Cum duobus ducibus de imperio in Italia est decertatum, Pyrrho et Hannibale; ab altero propter probitatem eius non nimis alienos animos habemus, alterum propter crudelitatem semper haec civitas oderit.

Ideo urbs venerabilis post superbas efferatarum gentium cervices oppressas latasque leges fundamenta libertatis et retinacula sempiterna velut frugi parens et prudens et dives Caesaribus tamquam liberis suis regenda patrimonii iura permisit.

Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.

Excitavit hic ardor milites per municipia plurima, quae isdem conterminant, dispositos et castella, sed quisque serpentes latius pro viribus repellere moliens, nunc globis confertos, aliquotiens et dispersos multitudine superabatur ingenti, quae nata et educata inter editos recurvosque ambitus montium eos ut loca plana persultat et mollia, missilibus obvios eminus lacessens et ululatu truci perterrens.

Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam vini: huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros.

Et quia Montius inter dilancinantium manus spiritum efflaturus Epigonum et Eusebium nec professionem nec dignitatem ostendens aliquotiens increpabat, qui sint hi magna quaerebatur industria, et nequid intepesceret, Epigonus e Lycia philosophus ducitur et Eusebius ab Emissa Pittacas cognomento, concitatus orator, cum quaestor non hos sed tribunos fabricarum insimulasset promittentes armorum si novas res agitari conperissent.

Cum saepe multa, tum memini domi in hemicyclio sedentem, ut solebat, cum et ego essem una et pauci admodum familiares, in eum sermonem illum incidere qui tum forte multis erat in ore. Meministi enim profecto, Attice, et eo magis, quod P. Sulpicio utebare multum, cum is tribunus plebis capitali odio a Q. Pompeio, qui tum erat consul, dissideret, quocum coniunctissime et amantissime vixerat, quanta esset hominum vel admiratio vel querella.

Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.

Dein Syria per speciosam interpatet diffusa planitiem. hanc nobilitat Antiochia, mundo cognita civitas, cui non certaverit alia advecticiis ita adfluere copiis et internis, et Laodicia et Apamia itidemque Seleucia iam inde a primis auspiciis florentissimae.

Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto Caesare, quem videri decuerat, ad praetorium cum pompa sollemni perrexit morbosque diu causatus nec regiam introiit nec processit in publicum, sed abditus multa in eius moliebatur exitium addens quaedam relationibus supervacua, quas subinde dimittebat ad principem.

Batnae municipium in Anthemusia conditum Macedonum manu priscorum ab Euphrate flumine brevi spatio disparatur, refertum mercatoribus opulentis, ubi annua sollemnitate prope Septembris initium mensis ad nundinas magna promiscuae fortunae convenit multitudo ad commercanda quae Indi mittunt et Seres aliaque plurima vehi terra marique consueta.
</p><p>

Primi igitur omnium statuuntur Epigonus et Eusebius ob nominum gentilitatem oppressi. praediximus enim Montium sub ipso vivendi termino his vocabulis appellatos fabricarum culpasse tribunos ut adminicula futurae molitioni pollicitos.

Quo cognito Constantius ultra mortalem modum exarsit ac nequo casu idem Gallus de futuris incertus agitare quaedam conducentia saluti suae per itinera conaretur, remoti sunt omnes de industria milites agentes in civitatibus perviis.

Ergo ego senator inimicus, si ita vultis, homini, amicus esse, sicut semper fui, rei publicae debeo. Quid? si ipsas inimicitias, depono rei publicae causa, quis me tandem iure reprehendet, praesertim cum ego omnium meorum consiliorum atque factorum exempla semper ex summorum hominum consiliis atque factis mihi censuerim petenda.

Montius nos tumore inusitato quodam et novo ut rebellis et maiestati recalcitrantes Augustae per haec quae strepit incusat iratus nimirum quod contumacem praefectum, quid rerum ordo postulat ignorare dissimulantem formidine tenus iusserim custodiri.

Nihil est enim virtute amabilius, nihil quod magis adliciat ad diligendum, quippe cum propter virtutem et probitatem etiam eos, quos numquam vidimus, quodam modo diligamus. Quis est qui C. Fabrici, M'. Curi non cum caritate aliqua benevola memoriam usurpet, quos numquam viderit? quis autem est, qui Tarquinium Superbum, qui Sp. Cassium, Sp. Maelium non oderit? Cum duobus ducibus de imperio in Italia est decertatum, Pyrrho et Hannibale; ab altero propter probitatem eius non nimis alienos animos habemus, alterum propter crudelitatem semper haec civitas oderit.

Ideo urbs venerabilis post superbas efferatarum gentium cervices oppressas latasque leges fundamenta libertatis et retinacula sempiterna velut frugi parens et prudens et dives Caesaribus tamquam liberis suis regenda patrimonii iura permisit.

Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.

Excitavit hic ardor milites per municipia plurima, quae isdem conterminant, dispositos et castella, sed quisque serpentes latius pro viribus repellere moliens, nunc globis confertos, aliquotiens et dispersos multitudine superabatur ingenti, quae nata et educata inter editos recurvosque ambitus montium eos ut loca plana persultat et mollia, missilibus obvios eminus lacessens et ululatu truci perterrens.

Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam vini: huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros.

Et quia Montius inter dilancinantium manus spiritum efflaturus Epigonum et Eusebium nec professionem nec dignitatem ostendens aliquotiens increpabat, qui sint hi magna quaerebatur industria, et nequid intepesceret, Epigonus e Lycia philosophus ducitur et Eusebius ab Emissa Pittacas cognomento, concitatus orator, cum quaestor non hos sed tribunos fabricarum insimulasset promittentes armorum si novas res agitari conperissent.

Cum saepe multa, tum memini domi in hemicyclio sedentem, ut solebat, cum et ego essem una et pauci admodum familiares, in eum sermonem illum incidere qui tum forte multis erat in ore. Meministi enim profecto, Attice, et eo magis, quod P. Sulpicio utebare multum, cum is tribunus plebis capitali odio a Q. Pompeio, qui tum erat consul, dissideret, quocum coniunctissime et amantissime vixerat, quanta esset hominum vel admiratio vel querella.

Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.

Dein Syria per speciosam interpatet diffusa planitiem. hanc nobilitat Antiochia, mundo cognita civitas, cui non certaverit alia advecticiis ita adfluere copiis et internis, et Laodicia et Apamia itidemque Seleucia iam inde a primis auspiciis florentissimae.

Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto Caesare, quem videri decuerat, ad praetorium cum pompa sollemni perrexit morbosque diu causatus nec regiam introiit nec processit in publicum, sed abditus multa in eius moliebatur exitium addens quaedam relationibus supervacua, quas subinde dimittebat ad principem.

Batnae municipium in Anthemusia conditum Macedonum manu priscorum ab Euphrate flumine brevi spatio disparatur, refertum mercatoribus opulentis, ubi annua sollemnitate prope Septembris initium mensis ad nundinas magna promiscuae fortunae convenit multitudo ad commercanda quae Indi mittunt et Seres aliaque plurima vehi terra marique consueta.
</p><p>

Primi igitur omnium statuuntur Epigonus et Eusebius ob nominum gentilitatem oppressi. praediximus enim Montium sub ipso vivendi termino his vocabulis appellatos fabricarum culpasse tribunos ut adminicula futurae molitioni pollicitos.

Quo cognito Constantius ultra mortalem modum exarsit ac nequo casu idem Gallus de futuris incertus agitare quaedam conducentia saluti suae per itinera conaretur, remoti sunt omnes de industria milites agentes in civitatibus perviis.

Ergo ego senator inimicus, si ita vultis, homini, amicus esse, sicut semper fui, rei publicae debeo. Quid? si ipsas inimicitias, depono rei publicae causa, quis me tandem iure reprehendet, praesertim cum ego omnium meorum consiliorum atque factorum exempla semper ex summorum hominum consiliis atque factis mihi censuerim petenda.

Montius nos tumore inusitato quodam et novo ut rebellis et maiestati recalcitrantes Augustae per haec quae strepit incusat iratus nimirum quod contumacem praefectum, quid rerum ordo postulat ignorare dissimulantem formidine tenus iusserim custodiri.

Nihil est enim virtute amabilius, nihil quod magis adliciat ad diligendum, quippe cum propter virtutem et probitatem etiam eos, quos numquam vidimus, quodam modo diligamus. Quis est qui C. Fabrici, M'. Curi non cum caritate aliqua benevola memoriam usurpet, quos numquam viderit? quis autem est, qui Tarquinium Superbum, qui Sp. Cassium, Sp. Maelium non oderit? Cum duobus ducibus de imperio in Italia est decertatum, Pyrrho et Hannibale; ab altero propter probitatem eius non nimis alienos animos habemus, alterum propter crudelitatem semper haec civitas oderit.

Ideo urbs venerabilis post superbas efferatarum gentium cervices oppressas latasque leges fundamenta libertatis et retinacula sempiterna velut frugi parens et prudens et dives Caesaribus tamquam liberis suis regenda patrimonii iura permisit.

Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.

Excitavit hic ardor milites per municipia plurima, quae isdem conterminant, dispositos et castella, sed quisque serpentes latius pro viribus repellere moliens, nunc globis confertos, aliquotiens et dispersos multitudine superabatur ingenti, quae nata et educata inter editos recurvosque ambitus montium eos ut loca plana persultat et mollia, missilibus obvios eminus lacessens et ululatu truci perterrens.

Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam vini: huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros.

Et quia Montius inter dilancinantium manus spiritum efflaturus Epigonum et Eusebium nec professionem nec dignitatem ostendens aliquotiens increpabat, qui sint hi magna quaerebatur industria, et nequid intepesceret, Epigonus e Lycia philosophus ducitur et Eusebius ab Emissa Pittacas cognomento, concitatus orator, cum quaestor non hos sed tribunos fabricarum insimulasset promittentes armorum si novas res agitari conperissent.

Cum saepe multa, tum memini domi in hemicyclio sedentem, ut solebat, cum et ego essem una et pauci admodum familiares, in eum sermonem illum incidere qui tum forte multis erat in ore. Meministi enim profecto, Attice, et eo magis, quod P. Sulpicio utebare multum, cum is tribunus plebis capitali odio a Q. Pompeio, qui tum erat consul, dissideret, quocum coniunctissime et amantissime vixerat, quanta esset hominum vel admiratio vel querella.

Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.

Dein Syria per speciosam interpatet diffusa planitiem. hanc nobilitat Antiochia, mundo cognita civitas, cui non certaverit alia advecticiis ita adfluere copiis et internis, et Laodicia et Apamia itidemque Seleucia iam inde a primis auspiciis florentissimae.

Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto Caesare, quem videri decuerat, ad praetorium cum pompa sollemni perrexit morbosque diu causatus nec regiam introiit nec processit in publicum, sed abditus multa in eius moliebatur exitium addens quaedam relationibus supervacua, quas subinde dimittebat ad principem.

Batnae municipium in Anthemusia conditum Macedonum manu priscorum ab Euphrate flumine brevi spatio disparatur, refertum mercatoribus opulentis, ubi annua sollemnitate prope Septembris initium mensis ad nundinas magna promiscuae fortunae convenit multitudo ad commercanda quae Indi mittunt et Seres aliaque plurima vehi terra marique consueta.
</p>

<p>

Primi igitur omnium statuuntur Epigonus et Eusebius ob nominum gentilitatem oppressi. praediximus enim Montium sub ipso vivendi termino his vocabulis appellatos fabricarum culpasse tribunos ut adminicula futurae molitioni pollicitos.

Quo cognito Constantius ultra mortalem modum exarsit ac nequo casu idem Gallus de futuris incertus agitare quaedam conducentia saluti suae per itinera conaretur, remoti sunt omnes de industria milites agentes in civitatibus perviis.

Ergo ego senator inimicus, si ita vultis, homini, amicus esse, sicut semper fui, rei publicae debeo. Quid? si ipsas inimicitias, depono rei publicae causa, quis me tandem iure reprehendet, praesertim cum ego omnium meorum consiliorum atque factorum exempla semper ex summorum hominum consiliis atque factis mihi censuerim petenda.

Montius nos tumore inusitato quodam et novo ut rebellis et maiestati recalcitrantes Augustae per haec quae strepit incusat iratus nimirum quod contumacem praefectum, quid rerum ordo postulat ignorare dissimulantem formidine tenus iusserim custodiri.

Nihil est enim virtute amabilius, nihil quod magis adliciat ad diligendum, quippe cum propter virtutem et probitatem etiam eos, quos numquam vidimus, quodam modo diligamus. Quis est qui C. Fabrici, M'. Curi non cum caritate aliqua benevola memoriam usurpet, quos numquam viderit? quis autem est, qui Tarquinium Superbum, qui Sp. Cassium, Sp. Maelium non oderit? Cum duobus ducibus de imperio in Italia est decertatum, Pyrrho et Hannibale; ab altero propter probitatem eius non nimis alienos animos habemus, alterum propter crudelitatem semper haec civitas oderit.

Ideo urbs venerabilis post superbas efferatarum gentium cervices oppressas latasque leges fundamenta libertatis et retinacula sempiterna velut frugi parens et prudens et dives Caesaribus tamquam liberis suis regenda patrimonii iura permisit.

Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.

Excitavit hic ardor milites per municipia plurima, quae isdem conterminant, dispositos et castella, sed quisque serpentes latius pro viribus repellere moliens, nunc globis confertos, aliquotiens et dispersos multitudine superabatur ingenti, quae nata et educata inter editos recurvosque ambitus montium eos ut loca plana persultat et mollia, missilibus obvios eminus lacessens et ululatu truci perterrens.

Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam vini: huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros.

Et quia Montius inter dilancinantium manus spiritum efflaturus Epigonum et Eusebium nec professionem nec dignitatem ostendens aliquotiens increpabat, qui sint hi magna quaerebatur industria, et nequid intepesceret, Epigonus e Lycia philosophus ducitur et Eusebius ab Emissa Pittacas cognomento, concitatus orator, cum quaestor non hos sed tribunos fabricarum insimulasset promittentes armorum si novas res agitari conperissent.

Cum saepe multa, tum memini domi in hemicyclio sedentem, ut solebat, cum et ego essem una et pauci admodum familiares, in eum sermonem illum incidere qui tum forte multis erat in ore. Meministi enim profecto, Attice, et eo magis, quod P. Sulpicio utebare multum, cum is tribunus plebis capitali odio a Q. Pompeio, qui tum erat consul, dissideret, quocum coniunctissime et amantissime vixerat, quanta esset hominum vel admiratio vel querella.

Thalassius vero ea tempestate praefectus praetorio praesens ipse quoque adrogantis ingenii, considerans incitationem eius ad multorum augeri discrimina, non maturitate vel consiliis mitigabat, ut aliquotiens celsae potestates iras principum molliverunt, sed adversando iurgandoque cum parum congrueret, eum ad rabiem potius evibrabat, Augustum actus eius exaggerando creberrime docens, idque, incertum qua mente, ne lateret adfectans. quibus mox Caesar acrius efferatus, velut contumaciae quoddam vexillum altius erigens, sine respectu salutis alienae vel suae ad vertenda opposita instar rapidi fluminis irrevocabili impetu ferebatur.

Dein Syria per speciosam interpatet diffusa planitiem. hanc nobilitat Antiochia, mundo cognita civitas, cui non certaverit alia advecticiis ita adfluere copiis et internis, et Laodicia et Apamia itidemque Seleucia iam inde a primis auspiciis florentissimae.

Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto Caesare, quem videri decuerat, ad praetorium cum pompa sollemni perrexit morbosque diu causatus nec regiam introiit nec processit in publicum, sed abditus multa in eius moliebatur exitium addens quaedam relationibus supervacua, quas subinde dimittebat ad principem.

Batnae municipium in Anthemusia conditum Macedonum manu priscorum ab Euphrate flumine brevi spatio disparatur, refertum mercatoribus opulentis, ubi annua sollemnitate prope Septembris initium mensis ad nundinas magna promiscuae fortunae convenit multitudo ad commercanda quae Indi mittunt et Seres aliaque plurima vehi terra marique consueta.
</p>
```

Comment: i know what's going on, but i ask how to fix it,is there any inbuilt method? or callback function for window.onscroll event.

Comment: check your answer before posting it, because it doesn't work, it scrolls more default ammount +20px

Comment: That's why I said, at the end of my answer "(I put y = 20 just for testing)"...... Now I put 5 again

Comment: nothing changed scrolll, still default scroll (thats why i say check answer)

Comment: No, It works! The problem is that the value 5 is to low to see anything because 5 pixels is too small. That's why I put the value 20 instead.

Comment: Well It does, try on this link may be: https://codepen.io/xam4lor/pen/xmaGVd. Try to change the value of the y parameters of the function 'scrollBy()'